# Why does the red arrow generate smoke when flying at high speed on a moon rocket?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]
Why does the red arrow generate smoke when flying at high speed on a moon rocket?  I think it is because of the structure, the air in this location has expanded, so the air in this location has created a low pressure, and condensed the water vapor.  right?

As shown in the figure below, the diameter of the rocket at the yellow line has changed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That's the location of a supersonic shock wave and the "smoke" behind it is condensed water vapor. You can see another shock further up near the top of the missile. These tend to form at changes in the diameter or the shape of the missile body.

Comment: Sometimes this phenomenon also appears on the upper surface of the wing.  Passenger aircraft are generally not supersonic.  Why is that?

Comment: Because as the air flows over the top surface of a wing, it accelerates. Even if the plane itself is subsonic, the airflow over the top of the wing can still be supersonic.